# Having problems using key arrows with pry in docker-compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, pry

I'm having a problem using the key arrows with Pry and docker-compose. Every time i try to use the key arrows i'm obtaining  ^[[A, for example. If i use irb in the terminal everything works without a problem.

I'm in a mac with BigSur 11.4 and using bash in iTerm.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Might it having to do with $SHELL in the container? [Referring to this Github issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2457)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on a Docker container hosted on my laptop (macOS Big Sur 11.6) when using the image `nginx`. My mistake was to access the container by taping `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID /bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`.

Once in the container, I solved it by taping `/bin/bash`in the terminal:

```
# ^[[A^C
# /bin/bash
root@6200d20b1931:/#
```